# Deploying hdfs core-site.xml with cloudera manager

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to add lzo support to my configuration files using the cloudera manager (CDH5b2).

If I add the `io.compression.codecs` to the service-wide hdfs configuration, and deploy the configuration file, `/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.hdfs/core-site.xml` now contains the new value.

However, `/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/core-site.xml` has a higher priority (`update-alternatives --display hadoop-conf`), the hdfs core-site.xml values are not used when I start a MR job.

Obviously, I can simply modify the yarn `core-site.xml` file manually, but I don't understand how to do deploy the hdfs `core-site.xml` file properly using cloudera manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a MapReduce Client Environment Safety Valve, also known as 'MapReduce Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for core-site.xml' found in the gui under mapreduce's configuration ->Service-Wide->Advanced will allow you to add any value that doesn't fit elsewhere. (There is also one for core-site.xml as well.)

Having said that, details can be found on Cloudera's site at: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html